How to combine old and new log results of the same object in different type into one search
I am tracking users in my logs. I used to save a string on info.userData that contains the username. Later, I transformed userData into an object that holds the same username in info.userData.id, meaning userData became an object and is no longer a string. Now, I'm trying to create a search that returns the list of all unique users.
I tried to search both the old and new way and then dedupe my results to get one list, but I'm unable to do it whatever I'm trying.
Example code: ( is changed obviously to my index)
index=<index>
| eval old = [search index=<index> | rename info.userData as username_old | dedup username_old | return $username_old]
| eval new = [search index=<index> | rename info.userData.id as username_new | dedup username_new | return $username_new]
| mvcombine delim="," old new AS username | dedup username
| table username


There's an easier way. Since any event will have either info.userData or info.userData.id, we can set username to whichever is present using the coalesce function.
index=foo
| eval username = coalesce(info.userData, info.userData.id)
| dedup username
| table username

